# Add-ons for your C# app

Tags: c#, plugins, assemblies

I have a C# program and I want to make it able to load addons. Addons are like that: You pass a control or form to it and it makes some changes to them.

Is there anyway to have dll addons and load them dynamically at runtime and pass controls??
If not Any Idea? What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/) to load and import the assemblies and the controls.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [Management Extensibility Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx).

Comment: Thanks 4 ur answer! Sry there must be just one answer to tick but yours was also great! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's possible and it works similar to other programming languages: Load the library and call methods to get names and stuff. One possible solution can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070787/writing-c-sharp-plugin-system).