# DLL Plugin system in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

My question would be how it would be possible to make a plugin system in VB.net (2010)
I'd want it to have the ability to work this way:

```
It would be a DLL File written in VB.Net
It could be loaded on startup (of the program) when placed in a specific folder (e.g. "\plugins\")
The DLL file would have the ability to read values from the base program, and run subroutines / functions. Basically full interaction with the program.


(I Know I probably have to write something big / hard for this but i'm all in it)
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to create a DLL project referenced to your main project in Visual Studio?

Comment: @droidl0gix Nope. I mean I want users of my program to be able to create .DLL extension plugins, put them in my program's /plugins/ folder for example that my program could load up when it starts.

Comment: @droidl0gix I've seen people do this in the .NET framework, a good example is my favorite imageediting program, PAINT .NET. It was written in c# and C++ in the .NET framework. [link]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paint.NET#Plugins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps. You will need to implement an IPlugin

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-a-simple-plugin-b6174b62
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/546639/How-to-create-an-easy-plugin-system-in-Csharp

You can also take a look to a similar topic here in stackoverflow
[Writing C# Plugin System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070787/writing-c-sharp-plugin-system)

Comment: Thank you so much! I will rewrite my program in C# just for this lol (I know i can convert c# to vb but i have way too much free time so..) Anyways thanks